# Changing background colour using js mouseover and mouseout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am supposed to change the background color of the div that contains a task to the color in each box when the box is hovered over. When the mouse is moved away, the background color should return to white. Why isn't my code working?

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="task1" class="task">
  <h2>Task 1</h2>
  <div id="t1_color_one" class="t1_colors" style="background:   hotpink;"></div>
  <div id="t1_color_two" class="t1_colors" style="background: lightgreen;"></div>
  <div id="t1_color_three" class="t1_colors" style="background: palevioletred;"></div>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.t1_colors {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(111, 61, 69);
}
```

Here's my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("t1_color_one").mouseover(function () {
        var $c = $(this).css("background-color");
        $("#task1").css('background-color', "black");
    }).mouseout(function () {
        $("#task1").css('background-color', "white");
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you including a link to jQuery?

Comment: we arent supposed to use jQuery. something to do with addEventListener

Comment: Well, apparently you are using jQuery.

Comment: WHAT!? are you kidding me. how do i use js then?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be about doing someones homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/avvw8r3a/7/)

JavaScript replacement of your jQuery code.

#### JavaScript:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('t1_colors');
var mainDiv = document.getElementById('task1');
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
        mainDiv.style.backgroundColor = window.getComputedStyle(this).backgroundColor;
    });
    divs[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
        mainDiv.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks dude, but how can the colors change to the ones we are given and not black?

Comment: its not going back to white though.

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo link](http://jsbin.com/xuzibu/5/edit?html,console,output)**

```
  var taskEl = document.getElementById('task1');
  var t1El = document.querySelectorAll(".t1_colors");

  for(var i=0; i<t1El.length; i++){
    t1El[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", hoverColor ,false);
    t1El[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", hoverColor ,false)
  }
  function hoverColor(event){
    var myColor = this.style.backgroundColor;
    if(event.type === "mouseenter"){
      taskEl.style.backgroundColor = myColor;
    }else{
      taskEl.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
  }
```

Here's a complete example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="task1" class="task">
      <h2>Task 1</h2>
      <p>Change the background color, of the div that contains this task, to the color in each box when the box is hovered over.</p>
      <p>When the mouse stops hovering over the box, change the background color back to white.</p>
      <div id="t1_color_one" class="t1_colors" style="background: hotpink;"></div>
      <div id="t1_color_two" class="t1_colors" style="background: lightgreen;"></div>
      <div id="t1_color_three" class="t1_colors" style="background: palevioletred;"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
      var taskEl = document.getElementById('task1');
      var t1El = document.querySelectorAll(".t1_colors");

      for(var i=0; i<t1El.length; i++){
        t1El[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", hoverColor ,false);
        t1El[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", hoverColor ,false)
      }
      function hoverColor(event){
        var myColor = this.style.backgroundColor;
        if(event.type === "mouseenter"){
          taskEl.style.backgroundColor = myColor;
        }else{
          taskEl.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        }
      }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you but i just realized it needs to be pure javascript. FML! :(